# How to run udev rule before a certain module loads?

Tags: nvidia, udev, macintosh, gpu

I am trying to get the nvidia GPU driver working on a Macbook Pro (running Arch Linux). According to the instructions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MacBookPro7,1#Nvidia), some PCI registers need to be set *before* the `nvidia` module gets loaded, otherwise it won't work. That paragraph also mentions that it can be done using a 'udev hook'; however, I am not sure how to do this in such a way that the udev rule will definitely run before `nvidia` gets loaded.

I have created the following udev rule (`67-Nvidia-320M.rules`):

```
# Udev rule to set correct PCI register values for NVidia 320M GPU
# this is required for proprietary NVidia driver to work properly

KERNEL=="card[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", SUBSYSTEMS=="pci", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x10de", \
ATTRS{device}=="0x08a0", RUN+="/root/Scripts/set_pci_registers.sh"
```

to run the following script, once the `/dev/dri/card0` graphics card gets detected:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to set correct PCI registers on boot for NVidia 320M GPU

# First, check to see if the driver has already loaded:

lsmod | grep nvid >> /root/pci_check.log

# Set pci registers:

echo "Registers before:" >> /root/pci_check.log
setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b >> /root/pci_check.log
setpci -s "04:00.0" 04.b >> /root/pci_check.log

setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b=8
setpci -s "04:00.0" 04.b=7

# Check registers are set correctly and output to a file:

echo "Registers after:" >> /root/pci_check.log
setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b >> /root/pci_check.log
setpci -s "04:00.0" 04.b >> /root/pci_check.log
```

The script is being run and the log file written to. However, it seems clear from the output that the script is running after `nvidia` has been loaded. How can I make a rule that will run before the module is loaded?

Comment: Why would you prefer *udev* to take care of this ? (rather than following the recommended method via a GRUB script I mean.) cf. https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple/MacBookPro/7-1#GPU_.2F_Nvidia_Geforce_320M

Comment: @MC68020 firstly, I am not using GRUB on this machine - I am using rEFInd instead (and I don't really want to complicate the setup by adding GRUB). Secondly, there have been suggestions in [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162289&p=4) that the GRUB/rEFInd options are not setting the PCI registers correctly. Thirdly, I am just curious how it would be done with udev, since the method is suggested in the linked Arch Wiki article, but no details are provided.

Comment: What if you  `modprobe -r nvidia` then `setpci.....` then `modprobe nvidia` ?

Comment: @don_crissti that is a good suggestion. I added it to my script and now it unloads the module before setting the registers, which I guess should work. Thanks very much! If you're inclined to post an answer, I'd be happy to give you the bounty.

Comment: However, doing that doesn't seem to have solved the underlying problem of getting the nvidia driver to work. When I try to start an X session, the whole system freezes and a kernel oops is getting reported in `kernel.log`. I suspect there may be a general issue with the nvidia module - perhaps it may have been broken by a recent update.

Comment: Well, it isn't really an answer... I was just thinking that setting the pci registers only requires that driver is not loaded (it shouldn't matter if it had been previously loaded as long as it's removed before `setpci` runs...). Anyway, if you manage to somehow make it work post an answer yourself, it'll be definitely more informative than my one-liner above :)

Comment: Since your rule targets the drm and the nvidia vendor, it is absolutely normal that udev waits for the driver to be loaded before executing. Now, don't your setpci commands only need the PCI subsystem to be loaded. Therefore should'nt *SUBSYSTEMS=="pci",  RUN+="/usr/bin/setpci -s '00:17.0' 3e.b=8"* and *SUBSYSTEMS=="pci",  RUN+="/usr/bin/setpci -s '04:00.0' 04.b=7"* be sufficient ?

Comment: @MC68020 I tried your suggestion; however I found that my script was being run hundreds of times during the boot sequence, with those pci registers seemingly being set to various different values during that time. Presumably, there are many pci devices that are appearing on the system during boot. I'm not sure having the script/commands run many times would be ideal?

Comment: Of course it was run a hundred of times. Now did at least one actually achieved the job you expected ? If affirmative there are now just many possibilities to get a far more restrictive condition.

Comment: @MC68020 yes, the current version of my script tests to see if the pci registers are set correctly and only resets them if they are not. During boot, they seemed to be getting set to various different values and the script was changing them back as needed. I have currently settled on the solution suggested by mattia.b89 below: to blacklist `nvidia` and then modprobe it in after all the pci 'register switching' has settled down.

Answer (score 2):

I would act in a slightly different way, that's **blocking** the module until I need:

1. prevent system from loading `nvidia` module by [blacklisting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel_module#Blacklisting) it
2. let your script does the job with PCI registers
3. only now, load `nvidia` module manually, maybe in the same script, at the end (*optional if module would be loaded automatically*)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this, but when I blacklisted `nvidia`, the rule didn't seem to trigger off of the video card (presumably because the driver isn't being loaded). So, instead I changed the rule to trigger off of the hard disk (`/dev/sda`), since that will obviously load very early in the boot sequence. That did seem to work and I loaded `nvidia` manually after boot. However, I still experienced the same problem with `nvidia` breaking the system. I suspect there is a more general issue with the module being broken.

Comment: Awarding you the bounty, as it's a good answer and was helpful. Thanks!